# How to update super attribute in a loop

Tags: python, inheritance

I am trying to update the attribute of a class and can't figure out how. Here's my code:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,variable_that_needs_updating):
        super().__init__()
        self.var = variable_that_needs_updating
        
    
    def runA(self, other_var):
        x = 2*self.var+other_var
        return x
        

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,initial_value_of_variable):
        super().__init__(variable_that_needs_updating=initial_value_of_variable)
    
    def runB(self, other_var):
        for i in range(10):
            other_var=1
            #can I do something like this:
            #super().variable_that_needs_updating = i
            output = super().runA(other_var)
            print(output)
        return output
```

How do I get it to update 'variable_that_needs_updating' to produce 1,3,5,7,... for output?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is: `self.var` and `self.runA(other_var)`. The child class has access to all the parent attributes.